# Swagger UI with polymorphism is not showing the correct model

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

My swagger UI (version 2.8.0) is not inferring well my model:

Audience.class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AudienceA.class, name = "AudienceA"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AudienceB.class, name = "AudienceB")
})
public interface Audience {
    void doSomething();
}
```

AudienceA.class:

```
public class AudienceA implements Audience {

    private String someStringField;

    public AudienceA(){
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething(){
        //do some stuff
    }

    public String getSomeStringField(){
         return someStringField;
    }
}
```

AudienceB.class:

Similar to AudienceA class.

SwaggerUI shows an empty model:

[image]

I was expecting something like displaying something about AudienceA or AudienceB model. Is this the expected behaviour of the UI?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your Swagger .yaml/.json file look like?

Comment: I'm not using a .yaml/.json file. I'm using Swagger with Spring Boot, just import the dependencies and runs autoconfigurated. But the question is, should show the entire model or is the expected behaviour?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the generated .yaml/.json file. Maybe this usage of annotations produces incomplete or incorrect API definition.

Answer (score -1):

Swagger has had its issues with polymorphism , especially Swagger 2.0. A lot of it these issues were corrected with Open API 3.0
You might want to look at following links to see how the polymorphism is handled in Open API 3.0

Open API 3.0 - https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/
Where as there is another post which probably addresses the issue mentioned by you here
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/swagger-swaggersocket/1z0f0pLplrM/WylVo2ioDAAJ